# Changing the call log in Android phone

Tags: android, logging, call, smartphone

The call log in the samsung galaxy note phone displays the log based on the date wise. It becomes very lengthy and occupies a lot of space and the log can hold only some limited number of call log. If we change the log based on the numbers and display the date wise details for every number it will be very useful.

Is this possible, if so how and what needs to be done?

Answer (score 2):

You are welcome to write your own call log application, using the `CallLog` `ContentProvider` as your data source.

You cannot change the existing call log application in the Samsung Galaxy Note, except by becoming a Samsung employee and working on that app, or by replacing the ROM completely with some ROM mod that contains a call log application that you prefer.